# Logo is not showing up on action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to simply put a logo on my ActionBar in android but nothing seems to be working.  I have literally tried every solution I could find on this website and others without any luck. Any help would be appreciated,

Jacob

Here is my java:

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);





        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home", "Find everything you need to know in one place", R.drawable.home_icon));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Learn About Our Programs", "Learn about what we do to help the city", R.drawable.list));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("About Us", "Get to know about us on the personal level", R.drawable.info_circled_alt));
        mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Contact Us", "Want to know more about something? Send us an email or phone call", R.drawable.questionm));

        // DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
        mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Drawer Item click listeners
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItemFromDrawer(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opem, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrawerClosed: " + getTitle());

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }


        };


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle
        // If it returns true, then it has handled
        // the nav drawer indicator touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }







    private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {


        // Close the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
        Intent intent;
        switch (position) {


            case 0:
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Home.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(i);


                        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;
            case 1:
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, FindOpp.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(i);


                        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);;
                    }
                }, 300);



                break;


            case 2:
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, About_Us.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(i);


                        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);;
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;

        }
    }


    }

class NavItem {
    String mTitle;
    String mSubtitle;
    int mIcon;

    public NavItem(String title, String subtitle, int icon) {
        mTitle = title;
        mSubtitle = subtitle;
        mIcon = icon;
    }
}
class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems;

    public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavItem> navItems) {
        mContext = context;
        mNavItems = navItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNavItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mNavItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView subtitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        titleView.setText( mNavItems.get(position).mTitle );
        subtitleView.setText( mNavItems.get(position).mSubtitle );
        iconView.setImageResource(mNavItems.get(position).mIcon);

        return view;
    }

}
class PreferencesFragment extends Fragment {


    public PreferencesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prefences, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you , try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```